# Merging two CSVs for replacing NaNs

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have 2 csv files, one with the original data with lots of both NaNs and empty spaces and the other csv file contains the answers for the NaNs.

How do i replace ONLY the NaNs with the contents from second csv file without changing any original values. Is there a easy solution with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.read_csv('training.csv',header=0)
b = pd.read_csv('training_predict.csv')

print 'input shapes', a.shape, b.shape
a[:,:29] = np.where(np.isnan(a[:,:29].values), b.values, a[:,:29].values)
a.to_csv('training_new.csv')
```

i tried using

```
a = a.fillna(b, inplace=True)
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two files are aligned and you just want to fill the cells, you could use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), depending on your preference:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([[10.0, 20.0, np.nan], [30.0, np.nan, 60.0], [np.nan, 80.0, 90.0]], columns=["a","b","c"])
>>> b = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=["a","b","c"])
>>> a
    a   b   c
0  10  20 NaN
1  30 NaN  60
2 NaN  80  90
>>> b
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
>>> a.where(a.notnull(), b)
    a   b   c
0  10  20   3
1  30   5  60
2   7  80  90
>>> a.combine_first(b)
    a   b   c
0  10  20   3
1  30   5  60
2   7  80  90
```

Comment: "It is not working" isn't much help as an error report. :-)  But like most `pandas` operations, these two don't act in place, they return a separate frame.  `a = a.combine_first(b)` would suffice if you want to change `a`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.read_csv('training.csv',header=0, nrows=7048)
b = pd.read_csv('training_predict.csv')

#a = a.where(a.notnull(), b)
#a = a.combine_first(b)
#a = a.where(~np.isnan(a), other = b, inplace = True)

a = np.where(np.isnan(a.values), b.values, a.values)

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = pd.concat([df,b],axis=1)
df.info()
```